# Highcharts Array syntax

Tags: commerce

i spent 2 days looking for a solution and I'm still looking for help.

i would like to create a chart using highcharts.
i need the syntax of the array to render.

i tested this solution and it works but i can't understand the syntax of the Options Array.

https://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/intro-visualization-api-part-2-highcharts-and-code#comment-3056

I need somebody who can explain the Syntax because .

Regards